# Newly Inserted Hive records do not show in Spark Session of Spark Shell

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I ran a simple program of Spark-sql to get data from Hive to Spark session using spark-SQL.

```
scala> spark.sql("select count(1) from firsthivestreamtable").show(100,false)
+--------+
|count(1)|
+--------+
|36      |
+--------+
```

Ran insert statements to insert 9 new records in the Hive table (directly on Hive console). Validated that Hive table has additional rows inserted properly.

```
hive> select count(1) aa from firsthivestreamtable;
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 4 seconds 520 msec
OK
45
Time taken: 22.173 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive>
```

But spark session which was already open doesn't show the newly inserted 9 rows. So, when I do count within spark session, it still shows 36 rows. Why is this happening?

```
scala> spark.sql("select count(1) from firsthivestreamtable").show(100,false)
+--------+
|count(1)|
+--------+
|36      |
+--------+
```

What is expected to be done in spark session to get the refreshed(new) data into the session? Actual no of rows in the Hive table now are 45 and not 36 as new data has been inserted.

It is in spark shell and the table in Hive is getting loaded through the Spark structured streaming API.

Comment: In a compiled program or spark shell? Assume former due to program. Not a streaming program?

Comment: In Hue the query will be executed using Map/Reduce program within Hive. So, this issue will not happen. Every time you run a Hue query (HQL) it triggers a map-reduce program underneath.

Comment: impala not the case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When Spark retrieves the table from metastore when accessed for the first time, it then lists the files and caches it in memory.
When we perform an `insert` operation, the records go into a **new** file which Spark will not be aware of. Two options.
 1. Trigger `REFRESH TABLE <tblname>` -> `spark.sql("REFRESH TABLE firsthivestreamtable")` .
 2. Restart the Spark application(The table and its file will be fetched again)

Comment: Totally different behaviour to if a JDBC source.

Comment: In Hue this does not happen.

Comment: Yes, it depends on the datasource's internal implementation. this problem will occur with file backed datasources(like Parquet, Orc, CSV, etc) where the listing of files(which is an expensive operation in cloud storage) is cached. In other datasource(like JDBC) this will not be an issue.

Comment: In Hue I will check.

Comment: My comment was more about differences

Comment: Does not occur with Spark Structured Streaming this aspect.

Comment: In Streaming,  file listing happens for every microbatch, to get the list of new files. There is no caching involved, unlike batch jobs.

Comment: But you can cache. The answer can be improved!

Comment: You can cache the data(using `.cache()` or `.persist`), but you cannot explicitly cache the file listings which are internal Datasource implementation.

Comment: I know, but I feel you can embellish the question, Good work.

Answer (score 1):

The clue to the story is that the observed behaviour here in Spark aids in recomputation of the DAG - if required to a Worker Node failure.

The other answer explains the mechanics, this answer the reasoning why.